# Is the validation accuracy always higher than testing accuracy in deep learning?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, object-detection, training-data

I met a professor who told me that generally speaking, validation accuracy is always higher than testing accuracy.
He claimed that testing dataset is used only for testing the final model. Although validation dataset is used to only tweak hyperparameters and only training data is shown to the model, the model developer could try to carefully pick the best model according to validation accuracies for numerous times of training.

However, since testing data is generally limited with the number of testing. For example, in some competitions, one evaluation for submitting the testing result per day is quite common. This way, we couldn't cherry-pick the best model which could achieve the best accuracy in both validation & testing datasets. Therefore, our best model which achieved the best results in validation data is usually not the best one in testing data. However, this speaker still believes so when the GT of testing dataset is released in some datasets.

I know that the data distribution in validation dataset and testing dataset is generally designed to be similar. However, this is not guaranteed. For example, in a general purpose object detection dataset, the "difficulty" between the same class of objects in the validation dataset and the testing dataset might be different. To be more specific, let's assume the detection target is person and we all know that small, occluded or truncated person is harder to be detected. However, it is practically difficult to control the distribution according to size, occlusion and truncation level in validation and testing dataset, accordingly.
Therefore, it is possible that the testing accuracy is higher than the validation accuracy when the GT of both datasets is available.

Answer (score 0):

**No**. There is no strong clue indicating which one would be higher unless a bias of sampling is identified or introduced.

Consider an extreme case in which your model is highly overfitting to the training set. The relationship between $p_{train}$, $p_{val}$, and $p_{test}$ are defined as below.

$$p_{train} = p_{val} != p_{test} $$

In this case, the validation accuracy would be significantly higher than testing accuracy, and vice versa.